# Table with filterable columns

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

I am trying to implement a dynamic table in React allowing the user to apply different filters per column (like in Google Spreadsheets, or Excel).

The idea is to develop such component from scratch without using third party libraries. Another requirement is to be able to get the applied filters from the table and process the logic outside of the component, i.e. a case scenario would be for a user to apply multiple filters to a N-row dataset via the table, while the actual filtering process is done on the back-end. Each column can only have one filter applied, and the symbol '?' is shown when an active filter is present. Upon clicking on the '?' symbol, the applied filter must be removed.

Currently, I am able to get the applied filters. However, the filter is not applied immediately. It seems the state updates are nor re-rendering the component as I expected.  See figures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am clearly a beginner in React and I think I am trying to be a little too creative, which is an indication that I am doing something wrong. I don't really know why, that's why I would like your opinions and suggestions.

Please find the relevant code below:

Table.tsx

```js
import {
  PropsWithChildren,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  // useReducer,
  useContext,
} from "react";
import {
  FiltersContext,
  FiltersDispatchContext,
  FiltersProvider,
} from "./TableContext";
import "./Table.css";

enum FilterActionType {
  ADD = "added",
  REMOVE = "removed",
}

type Filter = {
  operator: string;
  value: string | number;
};

interface AppliedFilters {
  [key: string]: Filter;
}

interface TableProps {
  primary: boolean;
  fontSize?: "smaller" | "small" | "medium" | "large" | "larger";
  hasColumnOptions: boolean;
  headers: string[];
  rows: { [key: string]: string | number }[];
  caption?: string;
  onFilter: (appliedFilters: AppliedFilters) => void;
}

const Table = ({
  primary,
  fontSize,
  hasColumnOptions,
  headers,
  rows,
  caption,
  onFilter,
}: TableProps) => {
  const mode = primary ? "table--primary" : "table--secondary";

  return (
    <FiltersProvider>
      <table className={["table", `fontSize--${fontSize}`, mode].join(" ")}>
        <caption>{caption}</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {headers.map((header, idx) => {
              return (
                <TableHeader
                  key={idx}
                  text={header}
                  hasOptions={hasColumnOptions}
                  onFilter={onFilter}
                />
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            return (
              <tr key={i}>
                {Object.keys(row).map((k, j) => {
                  return <td key={j}>{row[k]}</td>;
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </FiltersProvider>
  );
};

export default Table;

interface TableHeaderProps {
  text: string;
  hasOptions: boolean;
  onFilter: (appliedFilters: AppliedFilters) => void;
}

const TableHeader = ({ text, hasOptions, onFilter }: TableHeaderProps) => {
  const filterCtx = useContext(FiltersContext);
  const filterDispatch = useContext(FiltersDispatchContext);

  const [isFilterActive, setIsFilterActive] = useState(false);
  const [isHoverHeader, setIsHoverHeader] = useState(false);
  const [isDisplayMenu, setIsDisplayMenu] = useState(false);
  const [currentMenu, setCurrentMenu] = useState<
    "default-menu" | "filter-menu" | null
  >("default-menu");

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsFilterActive(!!filterCtx[text]);
  }, [filterCtx, text]);

  const handleCloseMenus = () => {
    setIsDisplayMenu(false);
    setCurrentMenu("default-menu");
  };

  const handleOpenMenu = (menuName: "default-menu" | "filter-menu" | null) => {
    if (menuName) {
      setCurrentMenu(menuName);
    } else {
      setCurrentMenu(null);
    }
  };

  const handleRemoveFilter = () => {
    filterDispatch({
      type: FilterActionType.REMOVE,
      header: text,
      operator: "",
      value: "",
    });
    setIsFilterActive(false);
    onFilter(filterCtx);
  };

  return (
    <th
      className={["table-header-cell"].join(" ")}
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHoverHeader(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHoverHeader(false)}
    >
      {isFilterActive && <span onClick={handleRemoveFilter}>?</span>}
      <span>{text}</span>
      {hasOptions && (isDisplayMenu || isHoverHeader) && (
        <OptionsButton
          isVertical={true}
          onClick={() => setIsDisplayMenu(!isDisplayMenu)}
        />
      )}
      {isDisplayMenu && (
        <HeaderOptionsMenu
          headerName={text}
          menuName={currentMenu}
          onCloseMenus={handleCloseMenus}
          onOpenMenu={handleOpenMenu}
          onFilter={onFilter}
        />
      )}
    </th>
  );
};

interface OptionsButtonProps {
  isVertical?: boolean;
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
  backgroundColor?: string;
  label?: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
}

const OptionsButton = ({
  isVertical = false,
  size = "small",
  backgroundColor,
  ...props
}: OptionsButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={["options-button", `options-button--${size}`].join(" ")}
      style={{ backgroundColor }}
      {...props}
    >
      {isVertical ? "\u22EE" : "\u22EF"}
    </button>
  );
};

interface HeaderOptionsMenuProps {
  headerName: string;
  menuName: string | null;
  onOpenMenu: (menuName: "default-menu" | "filter-menu" | null) => void;
  onCloseMenus: () => void;
  onFilter: (appliedFilters: AppliedFilters) => void;
}

const HeaderOptionsMenu = ({
  headerName,
  menuName,
  onOpenMenu,
  onCloseMenus,
  onFilter,
}: HeaderOptionsMenuProps) => {
  const filterCtx = useContext(FiltersContext);
  const [operator, setOperator] = useState("contains");
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState<string | number>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (filterCtx[headerName]) {
      setOperator(filterCtx[headerName].operator);
      setFilterValue(filterCtx[headerName].value);
    }
  });

  const filterDispatch = useContext(FiltersDispatchContext);

  const handleAddFilter = (
    header: string,
    operator: string,
    filterValue: string | number
  ) => {
    filterDispatch({
      type: FilterActionType.ADD,
      header: header,
      operator: operator,
      value: filterValue,
    });
    onCloseMenus();
    onFilter(filterCtx);
  };

  let menuContents: JSX.Element | null;

  switch (menuName) {
    case "filter-menu":
      menuContents = (
        <>
          <div>{headerName}</div>
          <label>Operator</label>
          <select
            value={operator}
            onChange={(e) => setOperator(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option>contains</option>
          </select>
          <input
            placeholder="Filter value"
            value={filterValue}
            onChange={(e) => setFilterValue(e.target.value)}
          />
          <hr />
          <div
            onClick={() => handleAddFilter(headerName, operator, filterValue)}
          >
            Apply
          </div>
        </>
      );

      break;

    case "default-menu":
      menuContents = (
        <>
          <div>Sort ASC</div>
          <div>Sort DESC</div>
          <hr />
          <div onClick={() => onOpenMenu("filter-menu")}>Filter</div>
          <hr />
          <div>Hide column</div>
          <div>Manage columns</div>
        </>
      );
      break;

    default:
      menuContents = null;
      break;
  }

  if (menuContents) {
    return (
      <DropDownMenu isVisible={true} onOutsideClick={onCloseMenus}>
        {menuContents}
      </DropDownMenu>
    );
  }
};

interface DropDownMenuProps extends PropsWithChildren {
  isVisible: boolean;
  onOutsideClick?: () => void;
}

const DropDownMenu = ({
  children,
  isVisible,
  onOutsideClick,
}: DropDownMenuProps) => {
  return (
    <DetectOutsideClick onOutsideClick={onOutsideClick}>
      <div className="drop-down-menu">
        <div
          className="drop-down-content"
          style={{
            display: isVisible ? "block" : "none",
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </DetectOutsideClick>
  );
};

interface DetectOutsideClickProps extends PropsWithChildren {
  onOutsideClick?: () => void;
}

const DetectOutsideClick = ({
  children,
  onOutsideClick,
}: DetectOutsideClickProps) => {
  const newRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick);
    };
  });

  const handleOutsideClick = (e: Event) => {
    if (newRef.current && !newRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
      if (onOutsideClick) onOutsideClick();
    }
  };
  return <div ref={newRef}>{children}</div>;
};
```

Table.css:

```css
caption {
    caption-side: top;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: light;
    color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
}

thead {
    font-weight: bold;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

.fontSize--smaller{
    font-size: smaller;
}

.fontSize--small{
    font-size: small;
}

.fontSize--medium{
    font-size: medium;
}

.fontSize--large{
    font-size: large;
}

.fontSize--larger{
    font-size: larger;
}

.table {
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.table--primary thead {
    color: white;
    background-color: #1ea7fd;
}

.table-header-cell span {
    padding: 0px 2px;
}

.table--primary tbody {
    color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: white;
}

.table--primary tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.table--secondary {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;
}

.options-button {
    color: inherit;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.options-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.options-button--small {
    font-size: small;
    padding: 1px 6px;
}

.options-button--medium {
    font-size: medium;
    /* padding: 11px 20px; */
}

.options-button--large {
    font-size: large;
    /* padding: 12px 24px; */
}

.drop-down-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.drop-down-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 160px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.drop-down-content div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: center; */
    font-weight : 400;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
    padding: 5px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-down-content div:hover {background-color: #eeeeee;}

.drop-down-content hr {
    size: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
}
```

TableContext.tsx

```js
import { Dispatch, PropsWithChildren, createContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const FiltersContext = createContext<AppliedFilters>({});
export const FiltersDispatchContext = createContext<Dispatch<Action>>(() => {});

export const FiltersProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [filters, dispatch] = useReducer(filtersReducer, {});

  return (
    <FiltersContext.Provider value={filters}>
      <FiltersDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </FiltersDispatchContext.Provider>
    </FiltersContext.Provider>
  );
};

enum FilterActionType {
  ADD = "added",
  REMOVE = "removed",
}

interface Action {
  type: FilterActionType;
  header: string;
  operator: string;
  value: string | number;
}

type Filter = {
  operator: string;
  value: string | number;
};

interface AppliedFilters {
  [key: string]: Filter;
}

const filtersReducer = (filters: AppliedFilters, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "added": {
      const result = { ...filters };
      result[action.header] = {
        operator: action.operator,
        value: action.value,
      };

      console.log("Hello from added filter");
      console.log(result);

      return result;
    }
    case "removed": {
      const result = { ...filters };
      delete result[action.header];

      console.log("Hello from removed filter");
      console.log(result);

      return result;
    }

    default:
      throw Error(`Unknown action: ${action.type}`);
  }
};
```

OutsideComponent.tsx

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import Table from "../../../components/Table/Table";

const headers = ["Person", "Most interest in", "Age"];
const rows: row[] = [
  {
    Person: "Chris",
    "Most interest in": "HTML tables",
    Age: "22",
  },
  {
    Person: "Dennis",
    "Most interest in": "Web accessibility",
    Age: "45",
  },
  {
    Person: "Sarah",
    "Most interest in": "JavaScript frameworks",
    Age: "29",
  },
  {
    Person: "Karen",
    "Most interest in": "Web performance",
    Age: "36",
  },
];

interface row {
  [key: string]: string;
}

type Filter = {
  operator: string;
  value: string | number;
};

interface AppliedFilters {
  [key: string]: Filter;
}

const TableWithHooks = () => {
  const [currentFilters, setCurrentFilters] = useState<AppliedFilters>({});
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState<row[]>(rows);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hello from useEffect TableContext");
    console.log(currentFilters);

    const filteredRows = rows.filter((row) =>
      Object.keys(currentFilters).every((header) =>
        row[header].includes(String(currentFilters[header].value))
      )
    );

    setFilteredData(filteredRows);
  }, [currentFilters]);

  const handleOnFilter = (appliedFilters: AppliedFilters) => {
    console.log("Hello handleOnFilter");
    console.log(appliedFilters);
    setCurrentFilters(appliedFilters);
  };

  return (
    <Table
      primary={true}
      fontSize={"medium"}
      hasColumnOptions={true}
      headers={headers}
      rows={filteredData}
      onFilter={handleOnFilter}
    />
  );
};
```